# GPG Python with Signed Git commits: Manually identify and verify the key that signed a commit

Tags: python, git, digital-signature, gnupg

I have Git repo with a bunch of signed git commits and a set of GPG public keys imported into my local keychain. I'm looking to (a) verify that the signature for a given commit is a valid signature, and (b) identify which GPG public key - which GPG fingerprint - is associated with that commit.

I'd prefer to use the GitPython module to determine this, but I'm not sure how to do either of these tasks. I can get the GPG signature out like so.

```py
from git import Repo
repo = Repo(repo_dir)
fifty_first_commits = list(repo.iter_commits('master', paths="dir/in/repo/", max_count=5000))
for c in fifty_first_commits:
    try:
        print(f"{'-'*50}\n{c.message}\n{c.hexsha}\n{c.gpgsig}")
    except:
        pass
```

Output:

```
--------------------------------------------------
 jaz

8193646322775885d2d11764eb6e8ab7e1fe92bf
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----

iQEzBAABCgAdFiEE7ut7Ul+zbFDPnPJVLm85QNTo9lcFAmFco3kACgkQLm85QNTo
9lfzrgf/VTzvZVleZpsu3V0v9HSSskZn7KME5yTpa6et6GV/V0YtCJFeD6u8BaHE
eVS7II/G9QKmNvuU4p2VVpKFFWE0bzehb46/LL3pu8oEJzGckHCurtHiRo5OsyME
bPkSQXS7rNEUoqjbGCI1O4+oB9sg9Btt3LHsFkMA5xh9fY9ISFbyV74eiM5Ckk0/
ZQelz1yD9RjIMC+jR0lyDzll4QlJi1y8rFKxv/Xg7LtoPCenxAkMurtDmbRIXR8I
Yvg8gMe13uUQbDkn5djz9/LDN34UHHDLdIqjklTEliFJQ3ou/7xsXqNKduQ79I8v
OXkJGhX+WuL2aZIibFkumgm2DbJEhQ==
=Czw1
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
```

However, I'm not sure how to identify the fingerprint of the key that signed the commit or how to know if the signature is valid with that key.

Basically, I'm looking to do with GitLab and GitHub do in their web interface, but I want to do this locally and programmatically. Preferably, I'd like to do this in Python, but can fall back to making subprocess calls to the gpg command if no python mechanism exists for this.

Any advice on how to verify a signed commit and determine what key (fingerprint) singed the commit?

Answer (score 0):

This is best done by calling out to GnuPG, because it does a lot of work for you.  The command line `git verify-commit --raw` shows you the raw output from GnuPG's `--status-fd` option, which you can parse to determine the information.  For example, here's some data from a commit I made (sanitized to exclude my email):

```
[GNUPG:] NEWSIG
[GNUPG:] KEY_CONSIDERED 88ACE9B29196305BA9947552F1BA225C0223B187 0
[GNUPG:] SIG_ID tBxmB0d8obBLpGcTmDHwH5fWN60 2021-10-03 1633296963
[GNUPG:] KEY_CONSIDERED 88ACE9B29196305BA9947552F1BA225C0223B187 0
[GNUPG:] GOODSIG 7C0C49628887A281 brian m. carlson <filtered>
[GNUPG:] VALIDSIG 082CE68A9DBC65FB83D1C3917C0C49628887A281 2021-10-03 1633296963 0 4 0 22 10 00 88ACE9B29196305BA9947552F1BA225C0223B187
[GNUPG:] KEY_CONSIDERED 88ACE9B29196305BA9947552F1BA225C0223B187 0
[GNUPG:] KEY_CONSIDERED 88ACE9B29196305BA9947552F1BA225C0223B187 0
[GNUPG:] TRUST_ULTIMATE 0 tofu
```

This means that the signature was made by the subkey 082CE68A9DBC65FB83D1C3917C0C49628887A281 which is part of the main key 88ACE9B29196305BA9947552F1BA225C0223B187.  The key is a version 4 EdDSA key (type 22) and the signature algorithm is SHA-512 (type 10).  Note that you will probably want to verify the signature algorithm used is not MD5 or SHA-1, since those are both known to be insecure.

Note that for a commit, the signature is stored inside a `gpgsig` (for SHA-1) or `gpgsig-sha256` (for SHA-256) header, or both.  The data signed is the entire commit data without any of those headers.  It may be the case that GitPython provides a way to extract these items separately, or it may be that you have to do it for yourself.

The algorithm for tags differs from commits.